An unusual uniqueness property for entire functions
For given $q\in (0,1),$ coefficients $|c_k|\leq Cq^{k^2/3},$ and non-negative non-decreasing convergent sequences  $\{a_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ and $\{b_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ satisfying $a_k\geqslant b_k,\;k=0,1,\dots $  consider two entire functions:
\begin{equation*} f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\frac{z+a_j}{1+a_j}\right)\quad \mathrm{and}\quad
g(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\frac{z+b_j}{1+b_j}\right).
 \end{equation*}
Question 1. If $f(z)=g(z),\;z\in \mathbb{C},$ does it follow that either $f(z)$ is a polynomial or that all $a_k=b_k$?
Question 2. If the answer is "no", what can be  stated about $a_k$ and $b_k$ under the condition $f(z)=g(z)$?
The problem arises in the investigation of the limit behavior of the $q$-Stancu polynomials as defined by G. Nowak in:
G. Nowak,  Approximation properties for generalized $q$-Bernstein polynomials,
J. Math. Anal. Appl.,  350(1) (2009), 50--55.

Shouldn't it be each $c_k$ term to power $k$ or the like?

Please double-check check formulae. As written, your $f$ and $g$ are linear functions. My guess is that the expressions in parenthesis should be raised to power $k$.

@Oleg Eroshkin Thank you for your remark. Yes, there was a misprint (Product is missing). I apologize for the error.

@Conrad Thank you for the remark. There was a misprint (product was missing), sorry for that.

Since initially there were obvious misprints, I'd like you to confirm that the coefficients $c_k$ are, indeed, exactly the same for $f$ and $g$.

@fedja Yes, the coefficients are exactly the same.
